# Store Leaflet-js ID, Lat and Lng to Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, leaflet

I'm trying to figure out how to store the ID number, lat and lng to a database. Primarily with this array below. I'm looking to have all the markers add to the database once you hit save, and each marker that I removed when pressing the remove button, be removed from the database.

To add markers I used:

```
$("#marker").click(function () {
  map.on('click', onMapClick);

   var markers = new Array();
   function onMapClick(e) {
    var marker = new L.Marker(e.latlng, {draggable:false});    
    map.addLayer(marker);
      markers[marker._leaflet_id] = marker;
    $('#overlay > ul').append('<li>Marker '+ marker._leaflet_id + ' - <a href="#" class="remove" id="' + marker._leaflet_id + '">remove</a></li>');
console.log(marker._leaflet_id + "," +  e.latlng.lat +  "," + e.latlng.lng);

 $("#savemarkers").on("click", function(){
      console.log(marker._leaflet_id + "," + e.latlng.lat + "," + e.latlng.lng);
//save all the markers lat and lng to db
 });
// Remove a marker
$('.remove').on("click", function() {
    // Remove the marker
    map.removeLayer(markers[$(this).attr('id')]);  
    // Remove the link
    $(this).parent('li').remove();
});
```

My table in MySQL goes as ID, username, password,  Lat, Lng, Email

Inside my db_const.php I have

```
 <?php
    # mysql db constants DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME
      const DB_HOST = 'localhost';
      const DB_USER = 'root';
      const DB_PASS = '######';
      const DB_NAME = '#######';
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First off `require_once("db_const.php");` is not JS, and is PHP so you need to add the necessary replacement to that file. Furthermore, if you are not defining a constant in a class, then your syntax is invalid. Please look at the docs. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

You define constants outside of class with the `define()` method.

Comment: thank you! I removed the require_once. I'll look into it much more. I'm very very NEW to php. So forgive my stupidity